# Error - TypeError: client.on is not a function (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I get this error:

```
Client.on("guildCreate", (guild) => {       
TypeError: Client.on is not a function
```

My code is:

```
const client = require("../index");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

client.on("guildCreate", (guild) => {
    let channelToSend;

    guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
        if (

            channel.type === "text" &&
            !channelToSend &&
            channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")

        ) channelToSend = channel;
    });

    if(!channelToSend) return;

    channelToSend.send(
        new MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(guild.name, guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setDescription("Thanks for inviting me my prefix is '?'")
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTimestamp()

    )


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the `client` correctly.

The [official documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) said to do that for creating the `client`:

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
```